# laravel-dompdf - Japanese IPAex gothic font is not working

Tags: laravel-4, dompdf, php-font-lib

I am using Laravel-dompdf to build my pdf file. Here's the open source project I used.
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/

The errors show when using Japanese ipaex gothic font family in pdf. I have been struggling for the day just to make pdf show me Japanese characters but it doesn't. Here's the error I got.

PS. I have setup everything like symbolic the vendor/phenx/php-font-lib folder to vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib folder.

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 12238' 
in /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/classes/Font_Table_post.php:59
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/classes/Font_Table_post.php(59): Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleError(8, 'Undefined offse...', '/home/vagrant/C...', 59, Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/classes/Font_Table.php(82): Font_Table_post->_parse()
#2 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/classes/Font_TrueType.php(307): Font_Table->parse()
#3 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/phenx/php-font-lib/classes/Font_TrueType.php(117): Font_TrueType->readTable('post')
#4 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/class.pdf.php(2353): Font_TrueType->parse()
#5 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/cpdf_adapter.cls.php(737): Cpdf->selectFont('/home/vagrant/C...')
#6 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/font_metrics.cls.php(122): CPDF_Adapter->get_font_height('/home/vagrant/C...', 24)
#7 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/text_frame_reflower.cls.php(167): Font_Metrics::get_font_height('/home/vagrant/C...', 24)
#8 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/text_frame_reflower.cls.php(332): Text_Frame_Reflower->_layout_line()
#9 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(711): Text_Frame_Reflower->reflow(Object(Block_Frame_Decorator))
#10 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/block_frame_reflower.cls.php(750): Frame_Decorator->reflow(Object(Block_Frame_Decorator))
#11 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(711): Block_Frame_Reflower->reflow(Object(Block_Frame_Decorator))
#12 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/block_frame_reflower.cls.php(750): Frame_Decorator->reflow(Object(Block_Frame_Decorator))
#13 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(711): Block_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL)
#14 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/page_frame_reflower.cls.php(123): Frame_Decorator->reflow()
#15 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(711): Page_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL)
#16 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php(949): Frame_Decorator->reflow()
#17 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/PDF.php(210): DOMPDF->render()
#18 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/PDF.php(156): Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF->render()
#19 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/PDF.php(193): Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF->output()
#20 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/app/controllers/OrderController.php(236): Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF->stream()
#21 [internal function]: OrderController->showInvoice('1')
#22 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(231): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#23 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(93): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('showInvoice', Array)
#24 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(62): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(OrderController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'showInvoice')
#25 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(967): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'OrderController', 'showInvoice')
#26 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}('1')
#27 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(109): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#28 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1033): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(1001): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(745): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/src/Middleware/Stack.php(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#33 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware.php(72): Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Stack->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#34 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Queue.php(47): Illuminate\Session\Middleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#35 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Guard.php(51): Illuminate\Cookie\Queue->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#36 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Illuminate\Cookie\Guard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 1, true)
#37 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(641): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /home/vagrant/Code/myPdfProject/public/index.php(49): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->run()
#39 {main} [] []
```

Here's my environment

- laravel 4.2
- barryvdh/laravel-dompdf (v0.4.6)
- dompdf/dompdf (v0.6.1)
- phenx/php-font-lib (0.2.2)

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a sample of the HTML?

Comment: @BrianS  Html code I used is very simple, simple as `<p>テスト</p>` just a single tag.

Comment: I don't know if it's an issue with the font itself or with php-font-lib. The PDF will render since these are actually just undefined offset notices (see [here](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=9f584f014c2c5ce90e29a5bfe52caca3)). You might need to adjust your application's error reporting so that it doesn't translate these into exceptions and halt execution. It also might be worthwhile to [create an issue](https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib/issues) with the php-font-lib project.